# Let's chain some tag cleanups

Tags: discussion, retag-request, clean-up

The [chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chain) tag is a bit messed-up. There are a bunch of meanings (as from the [history of the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20978147/revisions) and [excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20978148/revisions)) related to the term:

- the [CHAIN programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHAIN_(programming_language)) (if we really have such questions, I'd recommend retagging to [chain-lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chain-lang))
- the process of *chaining*. The tag wiki said: "*combine multiple processes or functions together to create a larger process or function*". Sounds a bit like [composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composition) or [piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piping) to me.
- the practise of [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) (seems to be the most popular). This is what the tag wiki describes, though the excerpt says that [method-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-chaining) should be used instead. We also have [chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chaining) with a matching tag wiki, these should likely be merged.
- the data structure *chain* - a linked list in effect. Used e.g. in [prototype-chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prototype-chain), [keychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keychain), [toolchain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/toolchain), [markov-chains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/markov-chains), [chain-of-responsibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chain-of-responsibility), certificate chains, [scope-chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scope-chain), etc.

Searching for [similar tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), [chained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chained), [chainable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chainable) and [chainability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chainability) should also be incorporated in the cleanup.

What do you think? **Do we need a separate tag for the generic data structure?** If you find [more programming-relevant meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_(disambiguation)), please edit this question. And of course **please help with the cleanup**, though there aren't that many questions (<300).

Comment: Isn't toolchain more about things like sending the output of one tool to the next? I'm not sure that I would want those types of questions conflated with the prototype chain, from, say, JavaScript. I would say I can be an expert in the prototype chain, but I'm certainly not an expert in toolchains (or keychains, or markov chains, etc.).

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting to merge those. But do we need a generic [tag:chain] tag for those questions that deal with kinds of chains that don't have their own tag?

Comment: Okay, got it. I misread what the list was about, my apologies. I agree, we don't need a standalone chain tag.

Comment: I just took the first question tagged with chain tag and it was actually about certificate chain as in certificate authority, so it's worth adding this to the list

Comment: @CamiloMartinez: Are there many enough that an own tag is worthwhile?

Comment: @Bergi Not that many around 9 as far as I can tell by running this query http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/206651/questions-tagged-store?tagname=chain but in many cases certificate authority [ca] tag could be used

Comment: 6 years later, how about it?

Comment: @Michael I'm all for it!

Comment: I was specifically searching for the merging of [tag:chaining] and [tag:method-chaining], saw [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284395/tag-merge-request-chaining-method-chaining) closed as a duplicate of this one, and so decided not to open my own. My concern with the proposal above (even though I agree with pretty much all of it) is that it covers too many cases, so nothing will end up getting done. It seems like it would be better to tease out a few into separate questions. WDYT?

Comment: @Michael If it's only about merging the [chaining] with [method-chaining], I think we should ask a mod to do that, and the question you linked is the appropriate way to go. I've voted to reopen it, if you do the same and leave a comment (and later an answer) that they should be merged and then cleaned up later (referring to this here) I'd hope to get this done. Or you write an answer suggesting the merge as the first step, then we upvote it and ask a mod to execute the request in two weeks.

Comment: Sounds good. I've voted to reopen as well.