# Tag merge request: [chaining] & [method-chaining]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, synonym-request

[chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chaining) is described:

> Chaining is an object-oriented programming technique where methods return the object on which they were called so that another method may be called on the same object, thus forming a method chain.

[method-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-chaining) has no description, but the term is all but used in the above description.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278970/lets-chain-some-tag-cleanups

Comment: I think the linked duplicate is more broad in scope than what was being proposed here so have voted to reopen. [tag:chaining] and [tag:method-chaining] are clearly identical based on the tag wikis and should be merged. [tag:chaining] is needlessly ambiguous.