# Should we create [postman-chaining] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-creation-request

This is a formal request to create the new tag [postman-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postman-chaining), using
the procedure described as
["you can request the creation of a tag by starting a new **meta discussion**"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252945)
.

Read on to get some basis for a decision as to whether this new tag is needed.

---

> Existing questions where the tag would be appropriate

There are currently [*two
questions*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postman+chaining)
which are tagged with both [postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postman) and [chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chaining).
But the tag [chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chaining) is poor - all two of these questions would
benefit from having it replaced by [postman-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postman-chaining).

---

> Explain why the tag and such questions are on-topic for Stack Overflow

The parent tag [postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postman) is already well established and clearly
on-topic. As of this writing, there are [more than 8,450 questions tagged
with [postman]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostman%5D+is%3Aquestion).
The suggested tag [postman-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postman-chaining) represents a sub-topic of
[postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postman), and there are already a number of posted questions that
need this tag.

---

> Explain how the tag helps in categorizing and finding those questions

This is the exact reason I would like the tag [postman-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postman-chaining) to be
created.

The already existing tag [chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chaining) is quite inappropriate for all two
of the questions mentioned above. *Chaining* in Postman has a vastly different
meaning compared to *chaining* as described in the tag wiki excerpt of the
[chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/chaining) tag, which reads:
[*Chaining is an object-oriented programming technique where methods return
the object on which they were called so that another method may be called
on the same object, thus forming a method chain.*](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chaining/info)

By contrast, *API request chaining in Postman* has a **very** different
meaning which should be obvious from the tag wiki suggestions below.

---

> Provide an initial tag excerpt and wiki for the new tag, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337).

#### My suggestion for the *tag wiki excerpt* (*usage guidance*) is:

*Use this tag for any question whose topic is chaining of web API requests in
Postman.
See the tag wiki description to learn more about request chaining in Postman.*

#### My suggestion for the *tag wiki description* is:

*A typical example of [request chaining in Postman](https://blog.postman.com/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/) is when some data resulting from one request is saved to a [Postman
variable](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/) and
then retrieved and used in a subsequent request.*

*Part 5 of the [Intro to Postman](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLM-7VG-sgbtAgGq_pef5y_ruIUBPpUgNJ)
video tutorial series explains in some detail how to make chaining requests
in Postman.*

*The [tag wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postman-chaining/info)
for **usage guidance** on when to use the [postman-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postman-chaining) tag reads:

"Use this tag for any question whose topic is chaining of web API requests in
Postman."*

---

> Propose a good fitting name for the tag as they are always lowercase,
> don't take spaces and have a maximum length of 35 characters.

I would prefer the name [postman-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postman-chaining).

Comment: Why wouldn't this questions be fine only with postman?

Comment: This is a bit of a power feature of postman that goes out of the realm of basic tool usage and into the realm of scripting, so perhaps the postman tag is a little too generic.

Comment: @Gimby, thanks! I really did not know how to respond ...

Comment: Well don't thank me yet as I've had time to mull it over with a cup of tea. This is a site about programming problems after all so actually a postman scripting question might just be exactly the kind of question you'd expect on Stack Overflow for Postman. A question about "how to do a post request" is probably just off-topic, it's basic tool usage, not a programming problem.

Comment: I agree that the `chaining` tags here should just be removed, leaving only `postman`. I use chaining in Postman in my day job, and it is not a distinct topic that warrants a separate tag. I question the validity of the `chaining` tag in the first place; maybe at least it should be renamed to `method-chaining`.

Comment: @Gimby But is it a tool "commonly used by programmers"? If so, then it's on topic.

Comment: @shadowtalker, I am actually trying to argue that *postman-chaining* ***is*** a distinct topic that warrants a separate tag. I would like to see the [tag:chaining] tag **replaced** by my suggested [tag:postman-chaining] tag rather than simply being *removed*.

Comment: @HereticMonkey not all questions about tools commonly used by programmers are on-topic. If it cannot be installed because of OS user rights problems - not a valid question for Stack Overflow, as a random example. Even if the tool in question is Visual Studio.

Comment: @shadowtalker. Concerning the [tag:method-chaining] tag - I was not aware that such a tag exists. When reading and comparing the excerpts for [[chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/chaining/info)] and [[method-chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/method-chaining/info)], I actually get the impression that they are in fact synonyms of one another. I could be wrong of course ... (just the first impression) ~ * ~ * ~ I might add that there is nothing *object-oriented* about [postman-chaining].

Comment: @henke yeah you have to really try hard to misunderstand what I'm saying to get to that comment.

Comment: @Gimby, sorry. I didn't *try* to misunderstand anything. But I take it that my previous comment did not make any sense, so I just deleted it. No big deal as far as I am concernced.

Comment: I noticed that someone (rightfully!) removed the [tag:chaining] tag from one of the three questions I referred to. I updated my question accordingly so as not to cause unnecessary confusion. (I replaced "three" by "two".)

Comment: At a rate of ~1 question per year, I really don't see the point. We should [make chaining a synonym of method-chaining](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278970/lets-chain-some-tag-cleanups) and leave it at that.

Comment: @Michael, I have tried to explain how [tag:postman-chaining] has nothing to do with *object-orientation* and that the tags [tag:chaining] and [tag:method-chaining] are therefore both *very poor* replacements for [tag:postman-chaining].

Comment: @Henke No, I understand that perfectly well. If the chaining tag were merged with method-chaining, and subsequently deleted, then the only possible tag which a user could add to their Postman question would be `method-chaining` which is clearly wrong. As a result, all Postman questions about chaining would be tagged with `postman` and that alone. Given how infrequently anyone tries to add the chaining tag, that seems fine to me.

Comment: @Michael > Given how infrequently anyone tries to add the chaining tag, that seems fine to me. ~ * ~ * ~ There are a ***lot*** of questions whose topic is [tag:postman-chaining], but are missing the tag [tag:chaining]. Are you saying I should start adding the [tag:chaining] tag that you yourself say "is clearly wrong"? I can't say I follow your line of reasoning ... ?

Comment: @Henke "*There are a lot of questions whose topic is postman-chaining*" You haven't provided any evidence of that. My opinion is that `postman` is sufficiently specific for those kind of questions and that more tags would not provide any benefit to discoverability.

Comment: @Michael you addressed the wrong user.

Comment: @Michael. *You haven't provided any evidence of that.* [Easy-peasy: 40 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostman%5D+chaining+is%3Aquestion). Is that too few to motivate the creation of the [tag:postman-chaining] tag? - I might add that there are 8,400+ [tag:postman] questions growing by as much as half dozen *on a daily basis*.

Comment: @Henke I'm not sure less than half a percent qualifies as "a lot". Also I don't know if you looked at the results, but I'd say that by skimming them myself, about a third of them are not related to the feature you're describing. 3 are to do with certificates, a couple feature the word 'chain' in a stacktrace, etc.

Comment: Do you believe that dividing the attention of all answerers that at most get 10 questions/day between two tag is really useful? The volume of questions on the main tag is a very strong argument for not creating more specific ones.